# Encode a 10bit raw video file

Tags: x264

I have a raw file that's in gray10le format. Each gray value is 2 bytes but only the first 10 bits are used. I can't seem to get x264-10b to accept it as an input.

```
x264-10b.exe --profile high10 --input-csp gray10le --input-depth 16 --fps 30 -o out.264 0_400x400_gray10le.yuv
raw [error]: unsupported colorspace `gray10le'
x264 [error]: could not open input file `0_400x400_gray10le.yuv'
```

I'm using the latest 10bit build at http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/x264/binaries/win64/

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT, it should be `--input-csp i400 --input-depth 10`

Comment: Tried: 
`x264-10b.exe --profile high10 --fps 30 --demuxer raw --input-csp i400 --input-res 400x400 --input-depth 10 --frames 100 -o out1.264 0_400x400_i400.yuv`
raw [error]: unsupported colorspace `i400'

Comment: Your binary is too old (June 2017).  Get the latest one. After Dec 2017, 8 and 10 bit support is present in the same binary.